# AWS Beanstalk Auto-scaling Scaling Triggers with UnhealthyHost count and Health Checking

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

I have my scaling triggers set to look for an un-healthy host count but it does not seem to be working.
[image: my configuration settings]

Now to test this - I am SSHing into one of my instances and halting the HTTPD service.  Then, when I navigate to the health overview, I will immediately see that the server I SSHd into now has the status of severe.

[image: severe === unhealthy?]

I would assume that at this point, after 1 minute has passed (as per my rules) a new server would be created, but that is not happening.

If I am understanding my rules correctly - there is now 1 (the above the upper threshold) unhealthy server, so we increment up 1.  And then once the number of unhealthy servers is 0 (below the lower threshold) then remove 1 sever.

But yeah, I waited around 5 minutes and no new EC2 servers were provisioned.

I also have some settings for the health check:

[image]

Is this conflicting with my autoscaling rules somehow?  I thought that the healthcheck file needs to return a 200 response to be considered healthy and if HTTPD is halted - they it would not return that response.

So what gives?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you left the units set, which I don't think exist on that metric.  You can go to the cloudwatch console and check the alarm and metric to see if they match.

But Also, scaling on UnHealthyHostCount is a bad idea.  Its just going to launch a new instance but not do anything about the unhealthy one.  Instead enabling ELB Healthchecks is usually a better idea.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environmentconfig-autoscaling-healthchecktype.html